# Could not get any response using Postman

Tags: rest-api, api, rest, account

I have been making a post call to Account from postman but I am unable to create a Account. But I am successfully create  a push Topic.

[image][image]

Comment: do you have mydomain enabled? Also are you behind a firewall?

Comment: what js mydomain enabled? I don't have firewall.